# Quelle est la différence entre les trois conjonctions « alors que », « pendant que » et « tandis que » ?

Tags: sens, conjonctions

Toutes les trois me paraissent de vouloir dire « *while* » en anglais. Je ne peux pas trouver une bonne explication ailleurs sur l'internet, bien qu'apparement l'un ait le sens de l'opposition, *tandis que* les autres ont le sens de la durée.

Comment: Dans mon commentaire, j'ai supposé que "trois" faisait références aux trois conjonctions (et conjonction est féminin, comme presque tous les mots en *tion). Du reste, "toutes les trois" et "toutes trois" sont toutes deux (^^) correctes. "tous deux" (et "tous trois", et "tous x") ont tendance à être plus fréquent puisque dès qu'un seul des éléments du groupe est masculin, il faut utiliser le masculin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En effet, elles se traduisent toutes par *while*, mais comme *while* a plusieurs sens en anglais, ça ne veut pas dire qu'elles soient exactement synonymes.

Les trois peuvent vouloir dire « au même moment » et exprimer ainsi la simultanéité temporelle

> *Pendant que* j'étais dans les bois, Soazig sonnait à ma porte.
>   *Tandis que* j'étais dans les bois, Soazig sonnait à ma porte.
>   *Alors que* j'étais dans les bois, Soazig sonnait à ma porte.

sont correctes et essentiellement synonymes. Dans ce cas *pendant* est le plus courant, *tandis* est assez soutenu ou vieilli et *alors* est plutôt rare. Précisément *pendant que* ne fait que signaler la simultanéité, alors que les deux autres impliquent une forme d'opposition, liée au paragraphe suivant.

*Alors que* et *tandis que* servent aussi à marquer une opposition entre des faits

> Fañch préfère les noix, *alors que* Gwenole aime les sardines.
>   *Tandis que Niamh* passait ses journées dehors, Aine devait rester à travailler dans sa chambre.

Dans ce cas, *alors que* est le plus courant, *tandis que* restant d'un registre assez soutenu. On pourrait aussi utiliser *mais*, voire rien pour un sens équivalent

> Muireann vit d'amour et d'eau fraîche, *alors que* Seán a besoin de luxe.
>   Muireann vit d'amour et d'eau fraîche, *mais* Seán a besoin de luxe.
>   Muireann vit d'amour et d'eau fraîche, Seán a besoin de luxe

Comment: Although I understand the individual words, I don't understand the meaning of "...vit d'amour et d'eau fraiche." She lived on love and fresh water? (But I understand the answer overall, it's excellent.)

Comment: OH it's an idiom, I found it. I get it now.

Answer (score 3):

J'aimerais ajouter que « tandis que » est mieux traduit en anglais par « *whereas* » qui marque un contraste plutôt qu'une contemporanéité.

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon. Merci pour avoir édité ma réponse, j'ai toujours des problèmes avec l'orthographe.